# generate ics calendar file with php

Tags: php, icalendar

When I open this calendar.php file, it's source code is a ics (calendar). I've cut out some code for event description, id, etc. to make shorter post. How can I generate such file by opening this php file? I think fopen but could You please help me with that?

opening calendar.php should generate calendar.ics (with all the data generated by this script)

```
    <?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id_employee='0100000001'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR \n";
    echo "PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN \n";
    echo "VERSION:2.0 \n";
    echo "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN \n";
    echo "METHOD:PUBLISH \n";
    echo "X-WR-CALNAME:Calendar \n";
    echo "X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Warsaw \n";
    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $h_start = $row['h_start'];
        $h_end = $row['h_end'];
        $schedule_notes = $row['schedule_notes'];

        echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
        echo "DTSTART:"; //20211227T190000
        echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $h_start)->format('Ymd');
        echo "T";
        echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $h_start)->format('His');
        echo "\n";
        echo "DTEND:"; //20211227T190000
        echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $h_end)->format('Ymd');
        echo "T";
        echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $h_end)->format('His');
        echo "\n";
    
        echo "END:VEVENT\n";
    }
    
    echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";
    
} else {
    echo "no data";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with that code? If you want to send this file as a file download, you don't need `fopen`

Comment: opening calendar.php should generate calendar.ics (with all the data generated by this script)

Comment: Ok. And what does it do instead exactly? Because it looks like it should generate an ics file...

Comment: Are you saying you want it to instruct the browser to offer the file as a download instead of displaying it in the browser window? If so, then simply set the appropriate HTTP headers before echoing anything.

Comment: I don't want to download the file. I want the script to create or update calendar.ics

Comment: You mean you want it to save the contents into a file on the server where the PHP is executing? In that case, instead of echoing the data, put it all into a string and then write the string to a file in one of the usual ways provided by PHP.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your quesiton by editing it. What do you mean by "create or update"? Is there only a single file under that name?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't really described the problem, but from what I see in the code, it is just outputting the ICS code. You probably want to send this to the user's browser, in a way that the browser understands that this is a file download. You need to add a few lines for that:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $icsFilename = 'my_calendar.ics'; // change this according to your needs
    header('Content-Type: text/calendar');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .  $icsFilename . "\""); 
    
    echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR \n";
```

The header calls need to come before the first echo. I'm assuming that nothing else is output by your script before the code shown above.

Comment: Will also need to remove the 4 spaces before the `<?php` so that headers will actually get sent

Comment: I don't want to download the file. I want the script to create or update calendar.ics